# Chartboost header file gives 18 errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chartboost

I am trying to integrate chartboost into my IOS game (I am coding in objective c). I followed the instructions on their website and when I tried to launch, the header file "charboost.h" contained 18 errors (I did not touch the file, it is as I downloaded). The errors are : 1) Function definition is not allowed here 2) Unknown type NSString 3) Expected a type 4) Cannot find interface declaration for NSObject, superclass of Charbtoost.

I am new to xcode and its probably something very simple I am missing, but I could not find how to fix this. Does any one know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any problem with Chartboost in SpriteKit game.

Here is sample test SpriteKitGame with Chartboost: [Download Here](https://app.box.com/s/pz5i9vgm9xx2fqglk7lzw8esi6n4r26j)

Comment: In my AppDelegate file? I did this in a first place.. (BTW, I am coding in objective c, not swift, as I saw most people have problems if using swift(

Comment: What is that? And where do I find the other one??

Comment: its a sprite kit  game

Comment: @LukasPaskauskas, I used Chartboost framework in spriteKit game without any problem..

Comment: I have literally followed a step by step guide they provide. None of the code I wrote gave errors, only the charboost.h file..

Comment: yes, it must be framework. Updated my answer with sample code